# How to use Groovy Style to add strings to a list and remove duplicates

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying use groovy to read and wirte with Excel files(.xlsx), and I have successfully have access with all the data in the Excel file, but my coworker told me that wasn't in groovy style; 
And I asked him what is the right way, he just typed following answer:

```
void function(){
        try{
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("D:\\GroovyExcelInsertion\\insert.xlsx"))
            // workSheet
            XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            //
            def lastRowNum = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
            def stringCellValue
            def list =[]
            for (int i = 0; i <= lastRowNum; i++) {
                XSSFRow row = sheet1.getRow(i);
                if (row != null) {
                    short cellNum = row.getLastCellNum();
                    for (int j = 0; j <= cellNum; j++) {
                        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                        if (cell != null) {
                            cell.setCellType(STRING);
                            stringCellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();

                            list.add(stringCellValue)
//                            list.findIndexOf { // This is what he worte for me.
//                                it == stringCellValue
//                            } ==-1
                        }
                    }
                }
                workbook.close();
            }
            println list
            println list.unique()
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I mean, do I use a (for) to do it, or something else.
I looked it up and the docs says this findIndexOf function can just return data when they matched and return -1 when not matched.
But I vaguely remember this can only return Integer no matter what, so pls help me if u can
Even with this:

```
def list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','a','b']
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    print list.findIndexOf { it == list[i] }
}

//The answer looks like this :  0123401
```

I really don't see how can this be sth that can remove duplicates.

Comment: so you just want to unique-ify values? `.unique()` does it but it's slow, e.g. `list.toSet().toList()` is faster.

Comment: yeah, but my coworker said not to use any already wirtten functions. This toList() thing really helped me out. Thank u so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh❤️